# Ansible playbook script failure

Tags: python, ansible

Getting error while running below playbook. The python script is on my master and I want it to run on two slaves. No idea what's wrong.

```
luckee@zarvis:~/playbooks$ ansible-playbook runscript.yml 

PLAY [droplets] ****************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [CentOS1]
ok: [CentOS2]

TASK [Run python script] *******************************************************
fatal: [CentOS1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/luckee/python/userfind.py", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
fatal: [CentOS2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/luckee/python/userfind.py", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @runscript.retry                                                                                                                                                 

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************                                                                                                                
CentOS1                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1                                                                                                                     
CentOS2                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1                                                                                                                     

luckee@zarvis:~/playbooks$
```

Here is the playbook.

```
---
 - hosts: droplets
   remote_user: root

   tasks:
   - name: Run python script
     command: /home/luckee/python/userfind.py
...
```

Looking forward for your help !

Comment: "No idea what's wrong" - well, it says `No such file or directory`. Try double check the file paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to execute a local file on a remote host.

If you meant to run it remotely you first need to transfer it or use the [script module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html). It first transfers the file to the remote hosts and then executes it.

```
- name: Run python script
  script: /home/luckee/python/userfind.py
```

If you meant to run the script locally, use delegation:

```
- name: Run python script
  command: /home/luckee/python/userfind.py
  delegate_to: localhost
```

---

To show the output of a task you first need to [register](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) the result and the print it out with a [debug](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html) task.

```
- name: Any task
  ...
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug: msg="{{ result.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Yes, it did work perfectly without any errors. But how can I get the output of the script from the hosts ? For ex - The script above searches for an user and prints something.

Comment: You can get the output of any module with `register`: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables If you want to show the output you can do this with a `debug` task. I added an example in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to transfer the script to the remote hosts and then run it:

```
---
 - hosts: droplets
   remote_user: root

   tasks:
   - name: copy the script to the remote host
     copy:
       src: userfind.py
       dest: /tmp/userfind.py
       mode: 0777

   - name: Run python script
     command: python /tmp/userfind.py
```

Fix the path as per your requirement